# How to apply custom theme in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have created my own theme in android studio and want to apply this theme but i cannot view  my custom theme in list (like other available theme) and therefore unable to apply.
Please see image which shows "Theme is not used anywhere."

Please anyone guide how can i apply my new custom created theme in android studio. Following is my resource file and image:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RaufTheme" parent="AppTheme" />

</resources>
```

[image]